# How to solve this division?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility

How to solve this division?

$$\pi^2z^2-\frac{2^3\pi^4z^4}{4!} |\overline{\ 1} \\ \iff$$
$$ 1\over{\pi^2z^2-{2^3\pi^4z^4\over4!}}$$

Please help me I don't know how to solve it.

Any hint will be welcome.

Thank you!

---

Note: $a|\overline{a}$ denotes $\frac{a}{a}.$

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"?  Are you trying to do polynomial long division?

Comment: @EricWofsey yes

Comment: @saulspatz I could not write the long division  symbol using mathjax

Comment: Write it as a fraction.  Do you mean $$1\over{\pi^2z^2-{2^3\pi^4z^4\over4!}}$$?

Comment: Or do you mean $$\pi^2z^2-{1\over{2^3\pi^4z^4\over4!}}$$

Comment: @saulspatz the first one.

Comment: @Alt. `I could not write the long division symbol using mathjax` Maybe [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21096) helps? Please clarify what you mean by `long division`, and by `solve`.

Comment: What kind of answer are you trying to get?  It won't be a polynomial.

Comment: @saulspatz well I don't know, it's homework. My teacher told me to do the division but I only get $1/\pi^2z^2$ as result and 0 as remainder. But I suspect it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply $1\over \pi^2z^2$ by the divisor, you get $1- {\pi^2z^2\over3}$  When you subtract that from the dividend, you get the remainder ${\pi^2z^2\over3}.$  Remember that you always have

dividend = quotient $\times$ divisor + remainder

so you don't have to just suspect that your first try is wrong.  You can confirm it.

**EDIT**

I think your teacher expects you to choose ${-3\over \pi^4z^4}$ as the quotient, because when doing a polynomial division, we normally start with the highest-degree term.  I'll let you figure out the remainder.

Comment: I see. what's the correct answer ?

Comment: I edited my answer to address this.